# BeanFactory not initialized or already closed call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the AplicationContext

Tags: java, spring

I got this error using spring

> BeanFactory not initialized or already closed call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the AplicationContext

I use this line of code

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
ShapeCollection shape = (ShapeCollection) context.getBean("shapeCollection");
```

Comment: You have to add the filename to the constructor: `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(<your application_context.xml>);`

Comment: yeah Jens U are right and Thank u so much ohh really i was confused now i got solution i did not add spring config xml file.